# Creating a Foreign Key based on an index name rather than table(columns)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a table with a timestamp field onto which I've created a composite index.

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_NAME_A" ON TABLE "A" (a_id, extract(year FROM created_at))
```

I have another table which stores a year and a_id which I'd like to have a foreign key relation.

I can't seem to find the syntax to do what I want.

```
ALTER TABLE "B" 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(a_id, a_year) 
  REFERENCES A(a_id, extract(YEAR FROM created_at));
```

produces:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
```

I've also tried ...

```
ALTER TABLE "B"
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(a_id, a_year) 
  USING INDEX "IDX_NAME_A";
```

Any Ideas?

```
Table A
--------
a_id serial,
created_at timestamp default now()

Table B
-------
b_id serial
a_id integer not null,
a_year date_part('year')
```

Comment: How about adding a year column to `Table A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A foreign key constraint cannot reference an index. It has to be a table.
A foreign key constraint cannot reference an expression. It has to point to column name(s) of the referenced table.
And there has to exist a unique index (primary key qualifies, too, implicitly) on the set of referenced columns.

Start by reading [the manual about foreign keys here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).

---

The superior design would be to just drop the column `b.a_year`. It is 100% redundant and can be derived from `a.created_at` any time.

If you positively need the column (for instance to enforce one row per year for certain criteria in table `b`), you can achieve your goal like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_id serial
 ,created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
 ,a_year NOT NULL DEFAULT extract(year FROM now())::int -- redundant, for fk
 ,CHECK (a_year = extract(year FROM created_at)::int)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_id_a_year_idx ON TABLE a (a_id, a_year); -- needed for fk

CREATE TABLE b (
  b_id serial
 ,a_id integer NOT NULL
 ,a_year int -- doesn't have to be NOT NULL, but might
 ,CONSTRAINT id_year FOREIGN KEY (a_id, a_year) REFERENCES a(a_id, a_year)
);
```

Updated after @Catcall's comment:
The `CHECK` constraint in combination with the column `DEFAULT` and `NOT NULL` clauses enforces your regime.

Alternatively (less simple, but allowing for `NULL` values) you could maintain the values in `a.a_year` with a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_a_insupbef()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

NEW.a_year := extract(year FROM NEW.created_at)::int;
RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER insupbef
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON a
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_a_insupbef();
```

Comment: If c_year is always supposed to be the year that's in created_at, I'd add a CHECK constraint for that, too.

Comment: @Catcall: good advice with the CHECK constraint! (Renamed to `a_year` to stay consistent with question.)

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out advise. I'm not really using created_at, but rather published_at which causes the DEFAULT to fail (since you cannot default based on the value of another column).  published at is an arbitrary date.

Comment: @DavidChan: (repost to fix typos) In this case I would go the trigger route (my alternative solution at the bottom), just based off of `published_at` and the fk with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.